# Admin WP not displaying all menus

Tags: css, wordpress, admin

I have got a strange issue as I have never seen this before. Got latest WP and in the admin, it left menu buttons keep disappearing and some keep collapsing each other. See photo. I have not touched and admin css or admin files. there is no any plugin activated. Any ideas where is a problem.
[image]

Comment: It's a Chrome bug. Use a different browser

Comment: Also if you collapse the menu it fixes it (while you remain on that page)

Comment: Works fine in Firefox. Thanks.